# Remove Video Description from Welcome Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, asset-library

The standard video welcome page includes a description field "VideoSetDescription" along with a few other fields like view count that cannot be modified. How can I remove it from the welcome page and put something else in its place? The edit in designer button is greyed out.